Name output of pmap on tibble
I want to loop over the rows of a tibble, one column should hold the name the corresponding slot should have in the output and the other columns are the arguments to the function.
I know how to solve that, but I was wondering whether there is any possibility to do the naming inside the pmap function?
library(purrr)
library(tibble)

params <- tibble(nm = LETTERS[1:2], x = 1:2, y = 2:3)

## this has one addional level of nesting
pmap(params, function(nm, x, y) {
  set_names(list(x + y), nm)
}) # %>% flatten would remove the unnecessary level

## correct format but mixes tidyverse syntax with base syntax
map(split(params, params$nm), ~ .x$x + .x$y)

## correct format & tidyverse syntax but naming must happen **outside**
pmap(params, function(nm, x, y) {
  x + y
}) %>%
  set_names(params$nm)

Expected result like in version 2 or 3, in tidyverse style, but without the necessity to rename the result afterwards.

Are you set on having them as separate objects, rather than using a list to house them? (e.g. paramsl$A, paramsl$B etc?

Of course I could do something like map(list(A = list(x = 1, y = 2), B = list(x = 2, y = 3)), ~ .x$x + .x$y) but this becomes rather clumsy w.r.t. to the input (which is hard coded). Thus, ideally the input remains in tibble format, but I am not adamant about this.

The way pmap works is that it takes the names from the names of the first argument so this does not do post processing of thepmap output but it does add such names before running pmap so that the input corresponds to what it expects.
params %>%
  mutate(nm = set_names(nm)) %>% 
  pmap(function(nm, x, y) {
    x + y
})

giving
$A
[1] 3

$B
[1] 5


You nailed it, I was aware that the names came from it's first argument, but I seemed to forgot that tibble/tidyverse preserves element names. Exactly what I was looking for. Thx.

I played a bit with your suggestion and, well, I have some more questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78314849/naming-of-elements-in-purrrmap any insights on that? B/c apparently names on first argument are not a sufficient condition.

What if something like this fully in tidyverse syntax?
params %>% 
  transmute(lst = as.list(x+y) %>% `names<-`(nm)) %>% 
  pull(lst)


I like this idea.  It requires, however, that the function is vectorized. This works here with + but in my real case the function is not vectorized, which means I will need something like . |> rowwise() |> mutate(my_fn(x, y))

Another option with pmap:
  pmap(params, function(nm, x, y) {
    as.list(x + y) %>% `names<-`(nm) 
  }) %>% 
    unlist(recursive = F)

